# Loading custom fonts in Nuxt/Tailwind Project

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

Hi everybody and sorry my english.

I have created a nuxt.js project with Tailwind. I´d like to custom my font family, so I downloaded some font files from Google Fonts. I have been reading Tailwind docs, but i can´t understand where do i have to place the font files and how to config Tailwind for loading the files.

I´d be very gratefull if somebody could help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the module @nuxtjs/tailwindcss.

1. First, you'll have to run `npm run build`, so that tailwind files are created:

   - ~/tailwind.config.js
   - ~/assets/css/tailwind.css
2. Create a folder `fonts` under `assets` and place the fonts you've downloaded.
3. Include your fonts in `~/css/tailwind.css`, as such:

```css
@include font-face( KapraNeuePro, '~/assets/fonts/KapraNeueProFamily/Kapra-Neue-Pro-Regular', 400, normal, otf);
@include font-face( KapraNeuePro, '~/assets/fonts/KapraNeueProFamily/Kapra-Neue-Pro-Medium', 600, medium, otf);
```

etc.

4. Check out tailwind's docs on how to add font families in `tailwind.config.js`, and which configuration better suits your needs:
   (the following one is a quick working example)

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ["KapraNeuePro"],
      serif: ["KapraNeuePro"],
      mono: ["KapraNeuePro"],
      display: ["KapraNeuePro"],
      body: ["KapraNeuePro"]
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: []
  }
};
```

5. Dont' forget to remove from your layout and page all the default CSS related to `font-family`

Answer (score 10):

Nuxt 2.12 and Tailwind 1.4.0 (assume you're using @nuxtjs/tailwind):

tailwind.css:

```css
/* purgecss start ignore */
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
/* purgecss end ignore */
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

/* add fonts here */
@import '~assets/css/fonts';
```

fonts.css:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Underground;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('~assets/fonts/Roboto.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('~assets/fonts/Roboto.woff') format('woff');
}
```

And in tailwind.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      roboto: ['Roboto']
    }
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
}
```

Then you can use this font globally, in your default.vue layout:

```js
<template>
  <div class="container mx-auto font-roboto">
    <nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
```

BTW, static is not for assets, like fonts, it's for files, like robots.txt, sitemap.xml

Comment: If anyone else is confused by this, nuxtjs/tailwindcss no longer generates a tailwind.css file by default: https://github.com/nuxt-community/tailwindcss-module/issues/253

Answer (score 7):

### Simplest Solution as of October 2021, Nuxt 2.15.7 & Tailwind 4.2.0

##### Add package

`yarn add --dev @nuxtjs/google-fonts`

##### Config with your font

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
  googleFonts: {
    families: {
      'Architects Daughter': true,
      // or:
      // Lato: [100, 300],
      // Raleway: {
      //   wght: [100, 400],
      //   ital: [100]
      // },
    },
  },
```

`tailwind.config.js`

```js
    fontFamily: {
      handwritten: ['Architects Daughter'],
    },
```

##### Use in your HTML

```html
    <h2 class="font-handwritten">
      This is a custom font
    </h2>
```

**Manually reload** the page, as hot reload might not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot ramigs.
After some hours of test-error, before to know your answer, i got another solution. I placed my font files inside a folder "fonts" i created inside "static" folder. In assets > css > tailwind.css:

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url('/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'OpenSans';
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url('/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

In tailwind.config:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
        fontFamily: {
             heading: ['Roboto', 'sans-serif'],
             body: ['OpenSans', 'sans-serif']
        }
    }
}
```

After that you have to use class "font-heading" or "font-body" in element you want. The font weight of font has to be relationated with font-weight classes of Tailswind.
Maybe we have now 2 different soluctions. Thank you again.